# MYSQL, update only certain rows of a table which satisfy certain conditons

Tags: mysql

This is wordpress database.It has two tables `wp_terms` and `wp_term_taxonomy`

```
wp_terms has columns slug, name, term_id
wp_term_taxonomy has columns term_id, taxonomy, term_taxonomy_id.
```

Now I try

```
UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = CONCAT(slug,'-quotes')
FROM wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag" AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
```

I am trying to concat the word in the rows of the column "slug" of table "wp_terms" which satisfy certain conditions.

but mysql gives

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy
>       WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag" AN' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` doesn't belong in an `UPDATE` statement.  If you want to join tables in an `UPDATE`, you can use `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE wp_terms
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
SET slug = CONCAT(slug,'-quotes')
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag"
```

You can also do this:

```
UPDATE wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy
SET slug = CONCAT(slug,'-quotes')
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag" AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
```

Comment: The second part is excatly what i was missing. Is it compulsory to use both tables after the UPDATE if the conditions WHERE are being related to both

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi:- Yes thats the way!

Comment: Ok. thats what i was missing. And couldnot find on net anywhere.

Comment: Also i want to know, how to check if the cell already has "-quotes". Else it will concat many times, if i by mistake run the command.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: Use [`SUBSTRING()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) like so: `AND SUBSTRING(slug, -7) != '-quotes'`.  Or better yet: `AND slug NOT LIKE '%-quotes'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
SET slug = CONCAT(slug,'-quotes')
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag"
```